# client/server https exchange key error

Tags: https, client-server, server

I want to do Client/Server communication with HTTP/HTTPS encapsulation.

The HTTPS mode is used just for encryption data, i don't need authentification.

For HTTPS connection, I created and installed certificat on server side.

Besides, i developped my server with HttpServerApi lib and my client (Windows) with WinHttp. So Client start request to server, there are a key exchange but the resultat is: Encrypted Alert (21) Decryption failed:

```
> 192.168.3.138   192.168.1.6     TLSV1 ClientHello
> 192.168.1.6     192.168.3.138   Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done 
> 192.168.3.138   192.168.1.6     TLSV1 ClientKeyExchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
> 192.168.1.6     192.168.3.138   TLSV1 Change Cipher Spec, Evrypted Handshake Message
> 192.168.3.138   192.168.1.6   TLSV1 Application Data, Application Data
> 192.168.3.138   192.168.1.6   TLSV1 Application Data, Application Data
> 192.168.3.138   192.168.1.6   TLSV1 Application Data
> 192.168.3.138   192.168.1.6   TLSV1 Encrypted Alert
```

this is the wireshark detail (server side), 192.168.3.138 is my client.

In the `192.168.1.6     192.168.3.138   TLSV1 Change Cipher Spec, Evrypted Handshake Message`, I've: Header checksum: 0x0000 [incorrect, should be 0x4ac1 (may be caused by "IP cheksum offload"?)]

How can i do the liaison between my server certificate and the port 443 or my Http Server developped?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i find "why Encrypted Alert". I think is just because i'm working with auto-signed certificate for my test!!

I've another question, with HttpServerApi, how can i select one certificate among others certificates?

Thank